# Running Debian 2.6 in RAM

Tags: linux, boot, memory, debian

I am currently trying to setup an embedded computer in order to load its filesystem into RAM, to avoid writing anything on the real disk but to run applications normally though.
Everything should run into RAM, the system should be able to be powered off at any moment, without any repercussion. I have been told to use ***ramfs*** to achieve this.

The OS is *Linux debian 2.6.32-5-486  i586*.

I know nothing about this subject, but I have tried the following:

I had this original /etc/fstab file content:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6ef[....]7f3 / ext2 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7ab[....]bd4 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/scd0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
```

Which I modified like this (the **(changed)** markers are not present in the real file):

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=6ef[....]7f3 / ext2 errors=remount-ro 0 1                (changed)
ramfs / ramfs defaults 0 1                                     (changed)
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=7ab[....]bd4 none swap sw 0 0                            (changed)
/dev/scd0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I do a "df -a" command, I approximately get this:

```
File system    Use%    Mounted on
ramfs          17%     /
tmpfs          0%      /lib/init/rw
proc           -       /proc
sysfs          -       /sys
udev           1%      /dev
tmpfs          0%      /dev/shm
devpts         -       /dev/pts
```

But I don't even know if this output is good or not, considering my concerns here.
All I can remark, is that, when I create a file in this configuration, it persists after rebooting. And I don't wish this behavior.

Can you please illuminate me a bit about the things I forgot and misunderstood?

Comment: Have you checked this procedure? http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/how-to-boot-os-into-ram-for-speed-and-silence-662116/

Comment: If you just want to avoid *writing*, you can simply mount the root filesystem read-only and use AUFS.

Comment: @Jakke: Im going to check this link, but I hope this works for debian ~2.6 too, because it is mentioned "Debian 4.0"...

Comment: @Daniel B: I tried earlier to set the rootFS in read-only mode and I got issues which I don't remember. But I didn't tried with AUFS, i'll test this too.

Comment: Of course, you need some directories to be writable. Fortunately, there’s a [guide of sorts](https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot) for this.

Comment: @user3535021 I would think that is the kernel version, not the debian release. To check your debian release, do `cat /etc/debian_version`

Comment: @Jakke Thanks for that clarification, indeed, my debian version is actually 6.0.3.

Comment: Well, the CompactFlash card which I was using has been corrupted after the failure of the disk image burning tool software that I was using. I am not able to continue my tests unfortunately.
I definitely think I should keep myself away from Hardware & Sys Admin tasks.

Comment: You could always use VirtualBox for experiments. ;) I’d recommend [USB Image Tool](http://www.alexpage.de/usb-image-tool/), if you’re using Windows, by the way.